# Можно ли каким-либо образом подключиться к MSSQL базе через фронтенд(VueJS), минуя backend?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, vue.js, frontend

Наткнулся на Knex.js, но так и не разобрался как этим пользоваться. Никаких коллбэков и промисов нет, как отследить состояние коннекта не ясно. Поднял у себя локально в докере MSSQL, пытаюсь туда достучаться из Vue приложения с помощью Knex – не выходит.

Возможно ли вообще соединиться с БД, минуя бэкенд и API?

Comment: Есть чудо - плагин, который добавит http api к mysql: http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/2014/mysql-5-7-http-plugin-mysql/

Comment: MS SQL, не MySQL ...

Comment: Пардон, но вообщем ответ не меняется, плагин для MSSQL - https://www.vaultproject.io/api/secret/databases/mssql.html

Comment: минуя бэкенд и API?

Comment: Поясните смысл фразы "Возможно ли вообще соединиться с БД, минуя бэкенд и API?"

Comment: Напрямую в БД, по аналогии плагинов для ноды.

Comment: Я думаю это плохая идея